# Explaining duality in linear programming using linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I am a student who has done mostly pure mathematics courses. I have no background in convex optimization. I have a good background in linear algebra and functional analysis.

I need to understand the (weak) duality theorem of linear programming in order to understand a paper. Most online resources give me long examples and intuitive explanations, instead of the rigor. Can you please explain this concept to me assuming linear algebra and vector space duality?

Comment: Have you tried any lecture video ??

Comment: https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/gale-duality-and-linear-programing/

Comment: Given your good background in linear algebra, you should be able to understand the (weak) duality theorems because not even eigenvectors nor Gram-Schmidt are involved in these theorems.  Despite its possible deep link with convex separation, for the finite-dimensional case (which is enough for LP), you don't even need real analysis.  The skills needed are just some basic inequality and definitions on matrix and vector products.  You may see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/426827/290189) to view the statement of the weak duality theorem.

Comment: Duality depends massivly on Farkas Lemma. This Theorem basically gives conditions for linear inequality systems to be solvable. This can be proved using Hahn Banach Theorem for separation of convex sets. A proof can be found in Rockafellar's Convex Analysis. The clue of duality in linear programming is to define your dual programm as needed by using Farkas Lemma. Weak duality can be proved without using Farkas Lemma only by the "right" definition of your dual programm. To get strong duality you need to construct a dual solution. This is done using Farkas Lemma.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會, the explanation given in that question is quite useful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Joppy, I was not pleased with the blog. Some of the text is very opaque.

Comment: @Christian it will be very pleasing to see a detailed account of what you have stated. I'll refer to the book you have mentioned.

Comment: WordPress renders math poorly.  Try blogging on [static sites](https://vincenttam.gitlab.io/test-hugo-staticman/posts/test-staticman/) instead.