# Linear programming and duality

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Choosing $n$-dimensional column vector $x$ to maximize $ax$ s.t. $Bx \leq c$ and $x \geq 0$, where $a$ is an $n$-dimensional row vector, $B$ an $m\times n$ matrix, and c an $m$-dimensional row vector. Let the lagrangian be $L(x,\lambda)=ax+\lambda(c-Bx)$, where $\lambda$ is an $m$-dimensional vector of multipliers.

Show that if $\bar{x}$ is a solution, with the corresponding vector of multipliers $\bar{\lambda}$, then 
$$L(x,\bar{\lambda}) \leq L(\bar{x},\bar{\lambda}) \leq L(\bar{x},\lambda) \quad \forall x \geq 0 \text{ and } \lambda \geq 0.$$

This question is as part of my optimization class and we barely talked about linear programming. So, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you assuming anything about what $\overline{\lambda}$ is?

Comment: @MishaLavrov it is the vector of multipliers when $\bar{x}$ is the solution

Comment: For completeness, it might be worth saying the conditions that a "vector of multipliers" has to satisfy, according to you, because those can vary slightly. (In particular, some people take the second inequality $L(\bar{x},\bar{\lambda}) \leq L(\bar{x},\lambda)$ as a requirement for this vector.)

Comment: If you plug in the definition for $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{\lambda}$, this is almost trivial.

Comment: Can you learn from the proof of the [weak duality theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/426827/290189) and **post your own attempts** to the question?